# How to align the column to the comma in longtable?

Tags: longtable, alignment, columns

First, a minimal working sample and its output are as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{ l | c | c }
\multirow{2}{*}{names}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{numbers} \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
&  number 1 & number 2 \\ \hline
Sir, 2008 & 10 & 9 \\ \hline
Madam, 1930 &  8 & 6
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see the first column is aligned to the left. **Then how to align the first column to the comma please?**

Comment: @M.Logic maybe you should clarify in your question exactly what you want, there a many answers to your question but if they don't fit to your main document they are pretty worthless

Comment: @JamesT I update the example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I rewrote this answer after the OP provided more information about their actual formatting objective(s).)

I suggest you use two columns instead of one column for the text material and make the `,` (comma) part of the intercolumn specification.

To handle rows in the header that don't conform to this formatting objective, I suggest you encase the cells in question in `\multicolumn{2}{l}}{...}` "wrappers". E.g., change

```
\multirow{2}{*}{names}
```

to

```
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{names}}
```

Next, change the blank cell at the start of row 2 to

```
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{}
```

Finally, don't forget to replace `\cline{2-3}` with `\cline{3-4}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ l | c | c }
\multirow{2}{*}{names} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{numbers} \\ \cline{2-3}
& number 1 & number 2 \\ \hline
Sir, 2008   & 10 & 9 \\ \hline
Madam, 1930 &  8 & 6
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ r @{,\space} l | c | c }
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{names}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{numbers} \\ \cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{} 
& number 1 & number 2 \\ \hline
Sir   & 2008 & 10 & 9 \\ \hline
Madam & 1930 &  8 & 6
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This method isn't specific to `longtable`. It works just as well with `tabular`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`, etc.

Comment: It solves the problem well. Thanks very much! By the way, It's strange that I used `\multicolumn{2}{l|}{}` yesterday but failed while I used it today but succeeded.